# showing empty array in after pushing data from foreach into it in asynchronous function

Tags: node.js, express, foreach, async-await, es6-promise

I'm new to async/await. when I print an array console.log shows an empty array [] but inside the loop, console.log shows data. Can somebody please help me where I'm going wrong.

```
    commandbody.forEach(async (command) => {
        const arrayC = await commandsModel.getbyId(command);
            cmdArray.push(arrayC);
    });
    console.log(cmdArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `forEach` function is not async-aware. You will need to use a simple for loop:

```
for( let i = 0; i < commandbody.length; i++ ) {
    let arrayC = await commandsModel.getbyId(command);
    cmdArray.push(arrayC);
}
console.log(cmdArray);
```

This should work if your outer function is marked as async too.

Comment: In inside async this is worked but how can I get data of cmdArray outside of async function

Comment: I don't know your specific case, but in generally you can only access the contents of the variable after the async has run. So you need to delay the accessing, for example with using a button or doing a setTimeout (which I wouldn't advice).